# Get the selected value from populating select options

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var regionOption = document.querySelector("#municipality");
var districtOption = document.querySelector("#districtName");
var provOption = document.querySelector("#region");

createOption(provOption, Object.keys(regions));

provOption.addEventListener('change', function() {
    createOption(regionOption, regions[provOption.value]);
});
regionOption.addEventListener('change', function() {
      createOption(districtOption, districts[regionOption.value]);
});
function createOption(dropDown, options) {
    dropDown.innerHTML = '';
        options.forEach(function(value) {
            dropDown.innerHTML += '<option name="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
};
```

CSS:

```
<select id="region" style="width: 125px;"></select>
<select id="municipality" style="width: 125px;"></select>
<select id="districtName" style="width: 125px;"></select>
```

So, I'm populating options for an empty select and I was wondering how to get the value of the selected option. I basically want to check if (select value = 'A' && another selecte value = 'B') { do something}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value attribute on each `<option>`:

```
<option value="' + value + '">
```

Then, simply check the `value` property on the `<select>`.

```
if (document.getElementById("region").value === 'A') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but the value is returning to empty

Comment: @Charan Are you checking in a change event listener?

Comment: @Charan Note that you need to set the value attribute on the option.

Comment: are you referring to the option attribute in the createOption function()?

Comment: @Charan Yes, you should set the value attribute on those created options.

Comment: @Charan I cannot reproduce the issue. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n46fx8mg/

Comment: just needed to use the change event listener. Thank you so much!